# creating jar file with mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I've created an application with java and mysql database, finally when I try to convert it to jar file with netbeans, it converted but not extract mysql connector with it in lib Folder, extract application only so when I try to open it from jar file I get this error message

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

how can I resolve that
Note : It's the first time to get this error , I recently update java version to java 9

Comment: this is your error message: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`?

Comment: yes, it's the first time to get it after java updating to version 9

Comment: why do you think it is an error message? I don't see anything wrong with it. Maybe you did not copy full message

Comment: I have login form in the application when I try to login this message disappear and I couldn't login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating you java to version JDK11 as Version 9 had compilation issues.  You can check the reviews.

If you use an environment like Eclipse which I recommend, Export to runnable jar and select 'Extract required libraries into generated jar.